# What prevents my AngularJs 2 application from running the commands shown in the inspector?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am experimenting with Angular 2. I use `npm start` to create a live coding environment in Chrome, and I am seeing unusual behavior.

An earlier version of my code base appeared as follows in the file A.service.ts:

```
export class AService{
    constructor( private http : Http ){}
    test( valueA : string, valueB : string ){
        var dataObj = { valueA, valueB }
        console.log( dataObj );
        console.log( this.http );
    }
}
```

After running my program, the console would successfully display two objects. The first object showed me values "valueA" and "valueB", and the second object was an Http object, which demonstrated to me that my service was properly loading, and the method is being called with the expected values. For future reference, we will call this console log pattern "Output A".

I changed my service definition. I changed it several times. The application would reload itself each time a saved a new version of the file. And on each version, I attempted to add code and console outputs to the service objects test method. However, on each iteration, only "Output A" would appear.

I deleted all the original lines of the test method, and I ran the code again, and still I see "Output A".

I follow the code execution in the inspector, and the inspector takes me line by line over the new code, which now looks like this:

```
export class AService{
    constructor( private http : Http ){}
    test( valueA : string, valueB : string ){
        console.log( "Testing AService. Method called successfully.");
    }
}
```

The debug line shows me that the next command executed should log to the console the string "Testing AService...", but instead of this, I see "Output A" from my previous implementation.  I have checked the .ts files, I have checked the .js files, and both show the new code base. Chrome shows the new code base, but the console is receiving log messages from the OLD code base.

I have used Ctrl-C to close the npm, and called `npm start` again, and still I see the output of the old code base....

This is truly perplexing to me! Any ideas on what might be happening?

Screen shot after browser cache wipe followed by system reboot:

[image]

**Update**

After rebooting the system and wiping all caches, I searched all the .js files again and found that my original code base WAS in fact in the .js files. The answer to my problem seems to lie in deleting these files and then restarting NPM.... something was preventing NPM from overwriting the JavaScript files when running the TSC application in watch mode.

Comment: you may need to restart whatever is running in `npm start` and clear the cache of your web browser and clear out the generated files (it would help to know if you're using webpack or something else to bundle the generated files)

Comment: If I am using webpack or some other file bundler, I am doing so unknowingly. On your advice, I have wiped my browser cache "to the beginning of time" for all value types. I have closed the npm server, the Chrome browser, and the IDE, and I have restarted the computer also.  Still,  I see the output from the old code base, which no longer exists in the visible files.

Comment: I can add that at the end of last week that I changed my package.json file to have the following setting: { "scripts: { "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ... } }.... this was done after another post recommended this alteration to the 'npm start' command to avoid a fatal error that was occuring on the second, third and forth times that I would attempt to run the Quickstart-seed package.json file using 'npm start' . The new script moves the "concurrently" identifier to the start of the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my problem seems to lie in deleting these files and then restarting NPM.... something was preventing NPM from overwriting the JavaScript files when running the TSC application in watch mode.

See update in original question.